# Formality of fixed points in the equivariant localisation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, equivariant-cohomology

Let $X$ be a complex algebraic variety equipped with an algebraic $\mathbf{C}^{\times}$-action. 
The Borel construction gives a map $f: \mathrm{E}\mathbf{C}^{\times}\times^{\mathbf{C}^{\times}}X\to \mathrm{B}\mathbf{C}^{\times}$, where $\mathrm{B}\mathbf{C}^{\times}$ is a classifying space of principal $\mathbf{C}^{\times}$-bundles (e.g. $\mathrm{B}\mathbf{C}^{\times} = \mathbf{P}_{\mathbf{C}}^{\infty}$) and $\mathrm{E}\mathbf{C}^\times$ is the universal principal $\mathbf{C}^{\times}$-bundle on $\mathrm{B}\mathbf{C}^{\times}$.

Then $X$ is called *formal* (in the sense of Goresky--Kottwitz--MacPherson) if the Leray spectral associated to $f$
$$
E^{pq}_2 = \mathrm{H}^p\left(B\mathbf{C}^{\times}, \mathrm{R}^qf_*\mathbf{C}\right)\Longrightarrow \mathrm{H}^{p+q}_{\mathbf{C}^{\times}}(X, \mathbf{C})
$$
degenerates at $E_2$.

Suppose that $X$ is formal with the given $\mathbf{C}^{\times}$-action. We can restrict this action to the $m$-th roots of unity $\mu_m\subseteq \mathbf{C}^{\times}$ for some $m > 0$.

**Question.** Is the subvariety of fixed points $X^{\mu_m}$ necessarily formal with the $\mathbf{C}^{\times}$-action restricted from $X$?

Intuition: The non-formality comes from orbits with finite stabiliser (large orbits). Taking the $\mu_m$-fixed points in $X$ amounts to removing certain large orbits while keeping the $\mathbf{C}^{\times}$-fixed points, which should make $X$ even more formal.

I could have formulated the question in terms of $\mathbf{S}^1$-actions on CW-complexes as well, but I'm only concerned with algebraic varieties.

Thanks.